# Reading values of a multi-dimensional array populated by xpath

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xpath, simplexml

I am a bit of a newbie to PHP and I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  I have an multidimensional array that I've created from an XML file using XPath. I'm able to move through the array and retrieve most all values but I am getting stuck on one section.

Example of XML structure:

- MasterNode

  - SubNodeItem1
  - SubNodeItem2
  - SubNodeItem3
  - SubNodeItemList

    - SubListItem

      - SubItemProperty1
      - SubItemProperty2
      - SubItemProperty3
    - SubItemList

      - SubItemProperty1
      - SubItemProperty2
      - SubItemProperty3
  - SubNodeItem4
  - SubNodeItem5

I am able to retrieve the value of any of the SubNode values by using the following syntax:

```
$val=$XML[$i]->SubNodeItem1;
```

however, I can not for the life of me figure out how to retrieve the values of `SubListItemProperty`.

I figured this would be the logical syntax:

```
$SubItemPropVal=$XML[$i]->SubNodeItemList->SubListItem[$i]->SubItemProperty1;
```

I have searched other forums and topics related to PHP multi arrays and have not been able to find the proper way to do this.

I am getting a `"Trying to get property of non-object"` error when I run the code.  I'm pretty sure that's the indication that I'm not pointing the node correctly.

Comment: Question number one: You already have an XML file with all the flexibility XPath gives you. Why would you want to give that up and use an array instead?

Comment: Do you actually have an multi-dimensional array populated from XML, or are you dealing with an XML object representation? If a multi-dimensional array you would not be using object access notation (`->`) at all. Please provide `var_dump` of your object in the question, it will be much more informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>My recommendation would be to keep the XML file, which apparently works fine already, and use it.</strike>

Transferring its elements into an array does not make much sense to me.

*EDIT: The OP does not actually use an array, but a SimpleXML object.*

XPath is extremely flexible and powerful in selecting the needed bits from an XML document:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($your_xml);

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

// for example
$result = $xp->query("//SubListItem[2]/SubItemProperty1");

if ($result->length)
{
    echo $result->item(0)->textContent;
}
```

---

SimpleXML would also work:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

// either this ($node will be an array of matches, or FALSE)
$node = $xml->xpath("//SubNodeItemList/SubListItem[1]/SubItemProperty1");

// or this (unless you add a number, [0] will be assumed)
$node = $xml->SubNodeItemList->SubListItem->SubItemProperty1;
```

Important: Array notation counts from `0`, while XPath always counts from `1`.

Note that the second option (array notation) will throw run-time errors when the structure of the document is not what your code expects.

With XPath there would simply be no return value, which is easier to handle (no try/catch block necessary, an `if ($node) { ... }` suffices).

Also note that with SimpleXML, the document element (`<MasterNode>`) *becomes* the document. So you would not use `$xml->MasterNode->SubNodeItemList`, but `$xml->SubNodeItemList`.

Comment: Well First all let me say WOW, this forum is impressive. So much helpful information within 5 minutes of posting!

First I suppose my understanding of xpath was a little off. I don't believe I have an array but instead i have an xpath object created by using: $xml = simplexml_load_string($result); ($result is a request recieved from an http post).  I think I understand your suggestion but in order to retrieve the SubItemProperty wouldn't I actually need to use: <br> $node = $xp->query("//SubNodeItemList/SubListItem[2]/SubItemProperty1");?

Comment: Ah, you're using SimpleXML, that was not obvious. (Note that you can use backticks to format `inline code`.) I'll add an example for SimpleXML to my answer. Your XPath looks fine, too. They'd both work, mine is just less specific. Of course more specific is better.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I'm curious to see your example as I can't find the right way to do this anywhere.

Comment: O.K. Here's is what was happening. I did assume the document element would become the actual document and my original xpath was reflecting that.  My error was that I hadn't looked at the var_dump to realize that the HTTP response was being included as a top level node... so I actually needed TO include that node in my XPATH.  I'm now able to retrieve all the values I'm looking for, BUT..... I am now getting another error when trying to put the values I need to save into an array-"Illegal offset type in.." is the error I'm getting.  I can echo out the value of the variable just fine.  Any idea?

Comment: SORRY for the premature question.  I figured out that I needed to convert to a string before saving into the array.  THANKS everyone!